# Update validation keys during runtime in IdentityServer

Tags: .net-core, identityserver4

I am trying to implement key rollover in *IdentityServer* but it seems the keys are only configured during startup.

The [Crypto docs](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/topics/crypto.html#signing-key-rollover) say that I should use `AddValidationKeys`. I can find out how to use them during startup in the [startup docs](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/topics/startup.html#refstartupkeymaterial) and that works perfectly fine.

Is it possible to use `AddValidationKeys` during runtime to handle key rollover so I do not have to restart the service to roll over the keys?

Answer (score 1):

It should be possible, but not out of the box. Identity Server 4 is extremely extensible and in regards to signing keys, it uses `ISigningCredentialStore` to retrieve the configured token signing keys. By default, it looks like it just injects and returns whatever you configure in the `Startup`.

You will need to create your own implementation of `ISigningCredentialStore` and add it to the DI. Identity Server 4 should then use the store to dynamically retrieve keys at runtime based on your business logic.

```
public class CustomSigningCredentialsStore : ISigningCredentialStore
{
    public Task<SigningCredentials> GetSigningCredentialsAsync()
    {
        // Your business logic to retrieve signing keys at runtime
    }
}
```